# Load a file content to be used in a test with JMeter and a AbstractJavaSamplerClient

Tags: java, jmeter, performance-testing

So there is something I'm missing here about how to use JMeter.

I was reading in the user guide that I can use a Java Sampler to run my test.
It's ok because I need to read a file with some content in it and then send it to the storage engine.

So I was starting writing some unit tests to implement my version of a JavaSample using the class AbstractJavaSamplerClient.

I was counting to load the file in the setup just once, but it puzzles me the fact that I can;t pass it to the runTest method using the sampler context.

How do you do something like this? I mean, obviously if I lose time loading a file each time the test has no meaning

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wouldn't it be easier to use [__FileToString()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__FileToString) function wherever it's required?

If you want the file to be read just one time [Once Only Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Once_Only_Controller) can be used to read the file into a JMeter Variable

If you're going to re-use the variable in multiple thread groups as vlns says it should be converted to JMeter Property as Variables scope is limited to current thread group only. See [How to Use Variables in Different Thread Groups](http://blazemeter.com/blog/knit-one-pearl-two-how-use-variables-different-thread-groups).guide for implementation details.