# How to put the content of a file in a global variable in JMeter?

Tags: file, variables, jmeter, jsr223

I want to save the content of a file in a variable one time and use it in JSR223 pre-processor script. 
How can I do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Load a file content to be used in a test with JMeter and a AbstractJavaSamplerClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25767654/load-a-file-content-to-be-used-in-a-test-with-jmeter-and-a-abstractjavasamplercl)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add [User Defined Variables](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421395-Using-User-Defined-Variables) to your Test Plan and define the variable name of your choice, i.e. `myFile`. As the value use [__FileToString() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__FileToString) and provide the path of the file which you want to load:

   [image]
2. Once done you can refer the file content from any of the JSR223 Test Elements using `vars` shorthand for [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class instance as:

   ```
   String myFile = vars.get('myFile')
   ```

   [image]